# How to make kendo grid fill 100% height between header and footer within a JQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

I have a jQuery UI dialog that has to have its height and width dynamically set after it opens. This contains a header div, Kendo-grid, and footer div. What I would like to do is to make the Kendo-grid scroll rather than the dialog; the dialog actually has to be be overflow:hidden for other reasons. In other words, I need the kendo grid (content) to fill 100% of the space between the footer and header. I am using knockout, knockout-kendo as well.

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="header">
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="kendoGrid: items"> </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p><a href="#">CLOSE</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/pbkBd/2/

I have attempted using this example to set the content height but not have been able to get this to work with my scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/dimodi/MjKmJ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the grid content height like this:

```
$(".k-grid-content").height('200');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayanthakgjls/pbkBd/4/

You can calculate the height and set it in the `resize` event in the window:

```
resize: function() {
  // user has finished resizing the window
  var height=<calculate Height>
  $(".k-grid-content").height(height);
}
```

Comment: Jayantha - the height must be dynamic though.  The dialog height is set dynamically, so the grid content height must be set dynamically as well. Ideally, this would just be pure css.

Comment: yes but you can call this with some dyanamic value while setting the dialog height.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following style to force the grid to fill:

```
.fillContainerGrid 
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.fillContainerGrid > .k-grid-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 69px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.fillContainerGrid> .k-pager-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```